# Guru hints not working in pgAdmin

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-1.18

Guru hints don't work on my pgAdmin (1.18.1) - no hint was ever shown, "Hints" item in "Help" menu is grey and even though I can set options for the hints, the changes won't save - when I open "Options" the next time, both fields are unchecked again. I ran the installer again to "repair" the install, but the hints are still not working.

So how to enable the hints?

Comment: Did you check that everything was fine in the options/preferences? http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.8/options-tab2.html

Comment: @KookieMonster: your link is for some very old pgAdmin, but the fields for guru hints are the same, just in different part of Options. Yes, this seems to work fine (that "Reset guru hints" unchecks automatically might be a feature), but regardless of this setting no hints appear and the "Hints" option in "Help" menu is still grey.

Comment: Sorry for the old stuff. Anyway, the guru hints won't be available everywhere. For example, I don't find it (using also 1.18-1) on a schema, but if you go down to schema/public/tables/mytable, you will find your guru hints and the "hint" option available. And in quite a few other places...

Comment: @KookieMonster: it wasn't over table, but when I click on a function, guru hints are enabled. Expand your comment to an answer an I will gladly accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will find valuable information in pgAdmin III documentation, and to be more precise in the settings page about [miscellaneous options](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/options-miscellaneous.html). You can check that Guru hints are enabled (unchek the *Do not show guru hints; I’m one myself box* if it's checked). You'll notice that guru hints won't be available everywhere, but only on some objects in you database, for example tables (saying something like "hey, what about defining a primary key for this table?"), functions and so on.

Good luck!